# Most efficient way of sending back an error response to the caller program in Java

Tags: java

I have a program called input shredder which shreds a physical document containing 20 logical documents. Each logical document passes through the a transformation process and the program at the end builds the physical document back with the transformed logical documents. I need to convey back to the shredder if a logical document fails conversion .. what would be the best way to send an error code back so that the shredder can write out the errored logical document to an error stream. ???

Comment: Are these modules of the same application or are these multiple applications? If they are multiple application: How do they communicate in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an exception when document conversion fails.  Catch it in the shredder.